# how to user input to arrays , in java foreach loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

[image: written codes]

---

[image: output]

trying input for arrays with foreach loop,
and expecting input all elements of array

thats not what I expect

```
   String[] exp=new String[5];
            for (String a:exp) {
                a=input.nextLine();
            }
            for (String a:exp) {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
```

Comment: What error did you encounter?

Comment: `String a: exp` put each value of exp into `a` for the loop block, and inside you give another value to `a` NOT to the array box

Comment: `b=5; a=b; a=6` doen't make `b==6`

Comment: You need to apply the contents of variable `a` to the `exp[]` array at a specific index. The `for/each` construct contains no current counter mechanism to do so therefore, you need to either add one or use a regular `for` loop such as: `for (int c = 0; c < exp.length; c++) { exp[c] = input.nextLine(); }`. If using a **for/each** loop: `int c = 0; for (String a : exp) { a = input.nextLine(); exp[c] = a; c++; }`. The `c` variable is used here as the index counter. Now the other `for/each` loop should properly display the `exp[]` array. You decide which is better and easier to read.